# Something wrong with weighting

Tags: blender, mesh, blender-2.67

I have some model, on which I am trying to weight some parts of mesh. On one part something goes wrong - part of textures of mesh is deforms on weight painting.
For example, if I use instrument Mix in Weight Paint, some textures goes sticky to some points, which located upper, than mesh:

[image]

If I am trying to remove these deformations with Subtract instrument, then some textures goes sticky to some points, which located lower, than mesh

[image]

How to fix these weight errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simpliest - press Normalize All button in Tools:

[image]